# How does Maven determine which plugin version to use for plugins used from the command line?

Tags: maven, maven-3

(using Maven 3.0.3 on Mac with Java 7)

When I run `mvn dependency:analyze-duplicate` maven uses the version 2.1 (no matter if 2.8 is available in my local repo or not) of the plugin and complains:

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'analyze-duplicate' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 among available goals unpack-dependencies,....
```

When I run it as `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze` it works fine.

I would have assumed, maven always falls back to the most recent version (even if not yet in the local repo), if no version is explicitly specified?

What am I missing? Thank you all for your time to respond.

Comment: have you resolved this? Very interested in solving this exact problem for the same reasons

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For some plugins Apache Maven has defined a default version in the one and only super-pom, which can be upgraded with a newer version of Maven. See the current trunk: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob_plain;f=maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml

```
<pluginManagement>
  <!-- NOTE: These plugins will be removed from future versions of the super POM -->
  <!-- They are kept for the moment as they are very unlikely to conflict with lifecycle mappings (MNG-4453) -->
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

In Maven-3.1 both the maven-dependency-plugin and maven-release-plugin have been upgraded. Previous releases still used 2.1 and 2.0 (in same order).

So these are the default if you haven't specify a version in your `pom.xml` or if you don't have a one.

To see the effective pom, execute `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom` or `help:effective-pom`, but then you rely (again) on the version in the super-pom.

Comment: thanks! i'm running user maven 3.0.5 and still had that problem. any idea where i can look at "my" copy of the super pom? to clarify the mistery

Comment: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5400, so I was wrong with the Maven version. I pushed it to 2.5, Herve to 2.8 a bit later, see https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=history;f=maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml;h=e8b42d87a082bd52d80f438d3b36cf424513a55b;hb=9404499ccdf27f6505ba4538130168c411f41eea . So yes, Maven 3.0.5 still points to m-dependency-2.1

Comment: @Ittai Use `mvn help:effective-pom` to display your effective pom (~merge of Super POM and project pom) and have a look at the plugin management section

Comment: Thanks! You solved a long-standing mistery :-) Can you please update your answer with the updated versions (and maybe even FrVaBe's addition about the effective pom so that it ties all the loops).

Comment: Thx a lot @Robert. Finally the mystery is solved. :) Hopefully they remove those configurations soon, so maven is acting more "predictable".

Answer (score 3):

The process of Resolving a Plugin's Version is described [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-resolution.html#Resolving_Plugin_Information).

In short Maven will use the first version found by this rules in this order:

- version defined in the project's POM
- version defined in the plugin registry (if enabled)
- LATEST version metadata
- RELEASE version metadata

So have a look in your project POM (or parent pom) if you specified a version for this plugin there.

**Update**: Regarding your problem the reason is, that the maven-dependency-plugin version 2.1 is specified in the pluginManagement section of the maven [Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM). Your project pom inherits these settings and therefore the version 2.1 is used by default (Upvote the answer of @Robert Scholte who pointed this out first!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem is that running your help-command it says `Name: Maven Dependency Plugin ... Version: 2.8` - but running it without a version mentioned still executed version 2.1 - even downloads it if missing.
And I also checked the pom file. It doesn't contain a reference to this plugin at all.
So my question is still not fully answered.
Maybe you can help me out in figuring out where to find the LATEST and RELEASE version metadata for a specific plugin? Especially for the dependency plugin. - Maybe this is the issue I am facing?

Comment: Checking out http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin I would assume that all versions up to 2.7 are correctly marked as release. Is this enough to trigger the "RELEASE version metadata"?

Comment: @Tom Fink Do you have a <parent> declaration in your pom?

Comment: In my local repository a `maven-metadata-nexus.xml` file is located inside the `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-dependency-plugin\` directory with the LATEST and RELEASE version information (we use a Nexus repository manager).

Comment: Deleted the `help:describe` section of the answer as this does not shows the plugin version actualy used.

Comment: Thx for your answers. Sry for my lare response:
I also have a similar xml file in that directory. It says:
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>2.9-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <release>2.8</release>
    <versions>...
And no, there is no <parent> declaration in the pom.
And the issue still occurs. :( Thx anyway. :)

Comment: And the ~/.m2/plugin-registry.xml also doesn't hold any reference to this plugin.